# Backbone collection change event fires, but nothing changes in the view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-events, backbone.js-collections

I am running the following view:

```
app.OrganisationTab = Backbone.View.extend({

el : "#organisations",

template : _.template( $("#tpl-groups-list").html() ),

events : {
    "click .js-edit-group" : "editGroup"
},

initialize: function() {

    this.listenTo(this.collection, 'change', this.change);

    var that = this;



    this.collection.fetch({
        success: function() {
            that.render();
        }
    })
},

change: function() {
    //this.$el.empty();
    console.log("collection has changed");
},

render:function() {
    this.$el.empty();
    this.addAll();
    return this;
},

addAll: function() {

    this.collection.each(this.addOne, this);

},

addOne: function(model) {

    var view = new app.GroupEntry({ 
        model: model 
    });

    this.$el.append(view.render().el);

},

editGroup: function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    var elm = $(e.currentTarget),
        that = this;

    $('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
        $('.modal-body').remove();
    });

    var organisation = this.collection.findWhere({ id : String(elm.data('groupid')) });

    var members = organisation.get('users');
    organisation.set('members', new app.UserCollection(members));

    var projects = organisation.get('projects');
    organisation.set('projects', new ProjectCollection(projects));

    var orgForm = new app.createOrganisationForm({
        model : organisation,
    });

    $('#myModal').modal({
        backdrop: 'static',
        keyboard: false
    }); 

}

});
```

This view triggers a new view, and in that I can change a model save it (sends a PUT) and I can get in my console, `collection has changed`. If I `console.log` this collection I can see that the collection has changed. If I try and re-render the page all I see are the models as they were without the edits.

Why would this be happening, when clearly the collection is getting changes as it fires the events and I can see it when I log the collection?

Comment: Did you you verify that the data is actually being saved in your database? That's my first guess.

Comment: It is certainly getting saved in the database, as a page refresh bring the new data in.

Comment: Ah, ok. I misunderstood. I thought re-render, meant reload.

Comment: No sorry on collection change I try to run render() which should empty the container, and add all the models...but it seems to render the old collection again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading your comment:

> No sorry on collection change I try to run render() which should empty
>   the container, and add all the models...but it seems to render the old
>   collection again.

You're getting this problem because you are overriding the `success` handler for the `fetch` call. That success callback is triggered before the models are placed in the collection. You need to listen to the [**sync event**](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog) if you want render after the collection has been *sync*hronized with the server (models are updated after fetch).

Update initialize to:

```
initialize: function() {
    this.listenTo(this.collection, 'change', this.change);
    this.listenTo(this.collection, 'sync', this.render);
    this.collection.fetch();
},
```